# how to fix property undefined error in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am unable to get why I am getting error that cannot read property. I am reading data from EndPonit API and my property name of json object which is label is correct. Actually,I am pushing data into array and making an array of objects. Here is my code. Can anyone help me please?Thanks
js code

```
 let airports=[];
 fetch('http://myApi')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(airportData=>{
          this.airports.push({
            'code':airportData.label.substr(0,3),
            'city':airportData.label.split(',')[1],
            'country':airportData.label.split(',')[2],
            'airportFullName':airportData.label.split(',')[3]
          });

    });
```

Comment: what is 'myApi' ?

Comment: Without knowing where the error is occurring, your possibilities are that "airports" is not defined, or that the "label" property of airportData is not defined.

Comment: Just reiterating what @Russ said.  You are defining the array as "airport", but in the fetch response you are trying to push to a different array airports (with an "s").  Probably the fix is to change the first line to "let airports = [];"

Comment: dont need to do this .then(response => response.json()) please remove this line

Comment: @WilliamWang Due to security reason I did not my complete url. However, I am accessing label from json and label is there in json objects.

Comment: @Russ Thanks for your response. By mistake, I have forgot to put s in the end of airport. Rest label property is defined and I tried to console the label and its work. But I do not now why property not found error is occuring..Please help. Thanks